# Perform JS function once two radio buttons are clicked?

Tags: javascript

I have some radio buttons:

```
<span id="price"></span>

<div class="optionTitle">Size</div>
<label class="productButton">
    <input type="radio" value="50" class="size" name="size"/>
    <b>50</b>
</label>
<br/>
<label class="productButton">
    <input type="radio" value="100" class="size" name="size"/>
    <b>100</b>
</label>
<br/>    
<div class="optionTitle">Color</div>
<label class="productButton">
    <input type="radio" value="red" class="color" name="color"/>
    <b>Red</b>
</label>
<label class="productButton">
    <input type="radio" value="blue" class="color" name="color"/>
    <b>Blue</b>
</label>
```

I want to change the `price` span to one of four values depending on which two radio buttons were checked. The caveat is the combinations are stored in a `<script>` tag:

```
var prices = {
    '50,red':'5',
    '50,blue':'10',
    '100,red':'150',
    '100,blue':'50'
};
```

How can this done in Javascript/JQuery? I've started a function which can be put in `onchange=""` for each of the four radio buttons:

```
function getPrice() {
    var $size = 0; // placeholder
    var $color = 0; // placeholder
    var $e = "" + $size + "," + $color;
    if ($size != 0 && $color != 0) {
        $("#price").text(prices[$e]);
    }
}
```

This will run the function on any radio button change but only change the span when two are selected. I'm not sure how to get the values for size and color from the radio buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this by first selecting the currently checked "size" and "color" radio buttons in your `getPrice()` method:

```
var size = $('input[type="radio"][name="size"]:checked').val();
var color = $('input[type="radio"][name="color"]:checked').val();
```

Then, you could use the two values from each input element, to create a lookup key to access a price from your `prices` table and display it:

```
var key = size + "," + color;
$("#price").text(prices[key]);
```

The selection syntax shown above can be thought of in the following way:

> `input[type="radio"][name="size"]:checked`
>
> basically means:
>
> get all `input` elements that have a `type` attribute of
>   `"radio"`, and a `name` attribute of `"size"` that are `:checked`

Here's a complete code snippet - hope that helps!

```js
var prices = {
    '50,red':'5',
    '50,blue':'10',
    '100,red':'150',
    '100,blue':'50'
};

function getPrice() {
    
    var size = $('input[type="radio"][name="size"]:checked').val();
    var color = $('input[type="radio"][name="color"]:checked').val();
    var key = size + "," + color;

    $("#price").text(prices[key]);
}

$('input[type="radio"]').click(getPrice);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="price"></span>
<div class="optionTitle">Size</div>
<label class="productButton">
    <input type="radio" value="50" class="size" name="size"/>
    <b>50</b>
</label> <br/>
<label class="productButton">
    <input type="radio" value="100" class="size" name="size"/>
    <b>100</b>
</label> <br/>

<div class="optionTitle">Color</div>
<label class="productButton">
    <input type="radio" value="red" class="color" name="color"/>
    <b>Red</b>
</label>
<label class="productButton">
    <input type="radio" value="blue" class="color" name="color"/>
    <b>Blue</b>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

use $input.attr("checked") does not work.

use $input[0].checked should work

```
function getSize(){
    if($("input[type=radio][value='red']")[0].checked){
        return "red";
    }
    else if($("input[type=radio][value='blue']")[0].checked){
        return "blue";
    }
    else{
        return "";
    }
}

function getPrice() {
    var $size = getSize();
    var $color = 0; // placeholder
    var $e = "" + $size + "," + $color;
    $("#price").text(prices[$e]);
}

$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    getPrice();
});`
```